# Running process from cmd.exe process inside thread executor service does not delete terminated processes

Tags: java, multithreading, process, terminate

I have a program that creates a lot of information and I take that information and throw it into a thread by way of

```
final static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

and pass it information via:

```
service.submit(new threadTry(str));
```

Where threadTry is the thread that takes the information, passes it inside command line arguments to generate a command, executes the command, then the cmd process runs the next process if criteria met.

Then the Executor service takes the list of submitted jobs, runs the 10 threads I've limited it to with the information given to them, creates a process which runs a command line window which can pop up another if a certain criteria is met. The command line window and the additional window that pops up do in fact terminate and the thread containing the command line window does terminate as well. The `ExecutorService` starts another thread with another bit of information. However, The cmd.exe and the other program are listed in windows 7 resource monitor as terminated. My program generates between 150-250 of these terminated cmd's/second (The handles to the javaw.exe process goes up and up with this). Only after I forcibly stop the main program, all the terminated processes are released.

My main problem is that I have to pass so much information that my program gets to about 56% done, then halts. I assume this is because the operating system cannot keep track of so many processes (even though they are terminated, but still listed). Halting is not caused by main program, it generates all information and terminates within 2 seconds (without doing anything with the info). With the processing of the information, my program takes about 2-3 hours to get to 56%.

```
public class threadTry extends Thread {
    String str="";
    public threadTry(String str){
        this.str=str;
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            String[] cmd={"...",str,"..."}; //input many arguments into cmd
            ProcessBuilder probuilder= new ProcessBuilder( cmd );
            Process process = probuilder.start();
            if(!process.waitFor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)){//if we wait longer than 5 seconds, 
              //then print this message (this is the standard wait for the process that 
              //waits until termination)
                System.out.println(str+": has exited with thread: "+this.getId());
            }
            int exitValue = process.exitValue();
            if(exitValue!=3){
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue+" For: "+str);
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
            }
            process.destroyForcibly();//does nothing to help clear the already 
              //terminated process
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any obvious problems with your code. Here are a few questions to help us narrow down the issue: Are you sure that the issue is caused by this code, and not by how you are implementing the thread pool? Is the cmd spawning any new processes of its own? Can you give us an example of the command you run in CMD? Note, making a new cmd process 150-250 times a second does not seem effective, if you can do this a better way then I imagine you will not suffer the same issue. Even a terminated process will still remain in memory a few seconds, and like you say it could very easily build up.

Comment: I am 100% certain that the problem lies within creating so many new processes, in turn, this code that generates them. Only sometimes the command will trigger another command window to run with another command, but these do terminate, but stay in the resource monitor with status Terminated, not really "gone" from the list of processes. As for providing a command, I cannot. As for making new cmd processes, I opted for the 10-threads approach because that was faster than just doing them one after the other for so much info. These terminated processes fill up the cpu list in the resource monitor

Comment: (continue from last comment) and show status "Terminated", but they all stay in list. The # of handles that the javaw.exe main java process holds goes up into the hundreds of thousands before halting. I've also tried the approach where I just make one new ProcessBuilder and remake the Process with the next command until all commands are sent (in one function, not in any thread). But the same problem occurs, just that it only makes cmd's about 15-25 times/second

Comment: About making a new cmd process per command, I'm not sure how to send over 250,000 commands in one cmd and get the return value for all. I think there is a limit to how much input the command line will take before saying that input is too long. Or is it possible to stream input to cmd and stream output to my program?

Comment: Streaming would cut the processes down to only a few but still take as long, I'm going to see if I can implement that. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good. If that doesn't work then remember that there are many different solutions to running hundreds of thousands of commands, however, we have no idea what sort of data you are processing. If you let us know then maybe we can offer a good suggestion. For example, a CPU intensive task should be run much differently from an HDD/storage intensive task.

Comment: It is a CPU intensive task

Comment: Have you tried using the process id to pass a kill -9? The destroy forcibly doesnt guarantee it will be killed. 
https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.process